# Laravel Route not defined when it is

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have this error.

[image]

And this simple code

```
<div class="copyright">
    <a href="/" id="footer-logo"><img src="/img/footer-logo.png"
            alt="Avel Developpement, votre toute nouvelle agence web spécialisée dans la création d'applications web et mobile dans la Loire. "></a>
    | &copy; {{now()->year}} | <a href="{{ route('mentions') }}">Mentions Légales</a> - <a
        href=" {{route('donnees-perso')}} ">Données personnelles</a>
</div>
```

and

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
Route::get('/mentions-legales', function () {
    return view('mentions');
})->name('mentions');

Route::get('/donnees-perso', function () {
    return view('donnees-perso');
})->name('donnees-perso');
```

I don't understand what is my mistake

Comment: is this route listed if you run `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: Make a **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65079298/edit)**, and post your code, instead of screenshot

Comment: @lagbox I actually have one route listed with a name (donnees-perso)

Comment: Because, your route has been cached, you need to clear your route with `php artisan route:clear` then try again